# Testing Angular reactive form validation

Tags: angular, forms, jasmine

I have an Angular 4 reactive form with validation, and I want to test the validation.

I set the `value` of the input native element to the value I want to validate, and I call `dispatchEvent` on the input element, but the `FormControl` element is not updated and the `valueChanges` is not triggered.

How do I make the `FormControl` recognize a change in the value, and how to I make it run the validators and emit a `valueChanges` signal?

This is the code I have currently.

```js
  inputElement.nativeElement.value = '-1';
  inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(errorDisplay.nativeElement.getAttribute('hidden')).not.toBeDefined();
    expect(errorDisplay.nativeElement.textContent).toContain('message');
  });
```